# Any way to retrieve current JBoss security-domain?

Tags: security, jboss, jboss6.x

Is there any way to retrieve the security domain that an application is running under other than by parsing the `jboss-web.xml`?

That is, the value specified under:

```
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/jboss-web-policy</security-domain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SecurityContextAssociation`

```
String securityDomain = org.jboss.security.SecurityContextAssociation.getSecurityContext().getSecurityDomain()
```